# After every kernel update I reinstall the Nvidia drivers and lose the Unity bar

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, kernel, 14.10

After each kernel update, after the reboot I don’t get anything on screen, therefore I switch to the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and reinstall the Nvidia drivers, then I reboot but I don’t get any Unity bar, just the wallpaper.

Therefore to fix it, I need to run, sometimes more than once, all these commands

```
  661  sudo unity --reset-icons 
  672  export DISPLAY=:0
  673  dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
  674  sudo unity --replace
  688  export DISPLAY=:0
  689  ccsm
  690  dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
  691  sudo unity --replace
```

Is there a fix for it?

14.10 x64, Nvidia 340.67, gtx 680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed DKMS and I didn't have to reinstall anymore the Nvidia drivers, I guess I solved it

> sudo apt-get install dkms

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (ubuntu 14.10 updated to latest kernel )recently  and lost all the menu/unity taskbar and what fixed for me was

```
export DISPLAY=:0   
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
setsid unity
```

Original answer and more explanations you can seek [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/290376#290376)

Comment: I reboot and I didnt have to reinstall the nvidia drivers, I guess because I installed also the dks trying to find a solution